# Redirecting won't work in certain MVC views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, view, http-status-code-404

So I've been making an MVC project but for some reason, some views work and others don't, whenever I try to show certain views I get this error:
[image]

It's in Spanish but it says the resource was not found even though the view is there in visualstudio? It's like visualstudio won't recognize certain views at random, or at least it seems random to me. I've checked that all the @Url.Action for every view that won't show up are correct and they all are.
Also on a side note, I deleted all the insert methods in a CRUD in another project and the project STILL inserted into the database even though there were no insert methods at all, again, it's like visualstudio doesn't recognize changes or certain documents stay in an older version or it doesn't recognize new elements added into the project. Any idea what this might be?

Comment: To be answerable the question needs [MCVE]. Additionally while editing the post make sure to use correct tags - MVC is for general questions about MVC design pattern, you probably want either "asp.net-mvc"or "asp.net-core-mvc".

Comment: Do you have file in this address?  `~/Views/Empleado/Index.cshtml`

Comment: Kindly provide the action method code for the view which is causing the issue

Comment: check your route of the view .the issue may be is of route URL Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enter the correct path, for example like this:

```
return Redirect("http://localhost:44373/Manage/Index/0");
```

And please pay attention, if your method has a parameter, then you have to enter it with.